# Failed to open and save monitior configuration

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, monitor, persistence

I try to use Ubuntu 12.04. from USB with a 4 GB peristent part.
First i changed some monitor settings (have two). After rebooting I got the error message:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors. Failed to open file  
     '/home/ubuntu/.config/monitors.xml.xml': Input/Output error
```

After this i changed the settings again. After pressing the save button I got following error.

```
Could not save the monitor configuration. Failed to create file  
     '/home/ubuntu/.config/monitors.xml.EO8ASW': invalid argument
```

I found some Questions with the same Problem. The answer is to delete the `monitors.xml` file. But I can not find the `.config` folder in the ubuntu folder.

How can I edit/delete the monitors.xml file, or how can i create a new one?

Answer (score 2):

With a few hours Google-Research i tried to fix the Problem by myself. I reset the complete System to the default setting. At the blank system there seems to be no monitors.xml config file.
After this i found a good tutorial how to create a monitors.xml file: http://www.sudo-juice.com/dual-monitor-settings-in-ubuntu/

First i created an empty xml file. After rebooting everything was still working, so I started to add configuration step by step with rebooting after each new setting.

Meanwhile all settings are stored in the xml file and system is working.